# How to get all the mac address from captured package?

Tags: tcpdump

tcpdump -i any -w all.cap
Now how to get get all the mac address from captured package?
Same mac address as one address.

Comment: You should make your question more clear and understanding, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install `tshark`

```
sudo apt-get install tshark
```

Now we have tool to read conntent of `.cap` file

With command

```
tshark -r all.cap -i eth0 -nn -e eth.src -Tfields
```

you will get output somethng like this

```
00:17:31:91:0c:8c
00:17:31:91:0c:8c
00:17:31:91:0c:8c
00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
00:17:31:91:0c:8c
00:17:31:91:0c:8c
54:a0:50:64:cc:39
00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
54:a0:50:64:cc:39
00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
54:a0:50:64:cc:39
00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
54:a0:50:64:cc:39
00:17:31:91:0c:8c
00:17:31:91:0c:8c
54:a0:50:64:cc:39
```

or you can modify commanad

```
tshark -r aalmac.pcap -i eth0 -nn -e ip.src -e eth.src -Tfield
```

and get output

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
    00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
xxx.xxx.xxx.40  00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
xxx.xxx.xxx.247 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
xxx.xxx.xxx.189 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
xxx.xxx.xxx.143 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
xxx.xxx.xxx.143 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
xxx.xxx.xxx.155 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
    00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.154 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
xxx.xxx.xxx.5   54:a0:50:64:cc:39
```

You can see that on some ip I have two or more mac address. That mean that ip comes to me from the same port on router.

Next you can modify command to look like this

```
 tshark -r all.cap -i eth0 -nn -e eth.src -Tfields | sort | uniq
```

and You will get sorted and unique mac <-> ip pair

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.154 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.69  00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.69  00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.143 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.155 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.23  00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.13  00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.247 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.77  00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.138 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
xxx.xxx.xxx.18  00:1e:8c:a8:3a:9b
xxx.xxx.xxx.205 00:17:31:91:0c:8c
```

...